# How to convert "float value 1232.0" to time format "12:32" (HH:MM) in panda/python?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a time column which has datatype as float and values as follows:

12:15 is written as 1215.0.

I am looking to fix this issue and set accurate datatype for this column alongwith correct representation of the time in HH:MM format

I am working in jupyter notebook (panda/python)

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. You could convert to a string and then do various string operations on the value. You could check to see if the value is between 0-60, 100-1259, and divide by 10 to get hours and pseudo minutes. How will seconds be represented? As decimal fractions of seconds? Or as 2-digit seconds plus multidigit decimal fractions of seconds? I think you'll find that if you think about it, a number of solutions, and problems, will come to mind. (If you still want the question answered, answer the above questions in the post, as it's currently too vague to respond to.

Answer (score 0):

Do perform necessary checks to see whether the time is valid or not.

```
f = 1215.0
x = int (f) //1215

hr = x / 100 //12
min = x % 100 //15

time = "{}:{}".format(hr, min) // 12:15
```